# Using Ajax method call in Asp.net application

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, session

i have this aspx view :

```
 jQuery('#addjob').click(function () {
            if ($('#metier').val().length > 0) {
                $('.taglist').append('<li style="line-height: 20px"><a href="" style="width:250px" >' + $('#metier').val() + '<span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "JobsEdition.aspx/AjouterMetier",
                    data: "{'job': '" + $('#metier').val() + "'}",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
                                              }
            $('#metier').val('');
        });
```

This is the result i got:

[image: im2]

In the code behin i put this method :

```
 public partial class JobsEdition : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      List<string> jobs = new List<string>();
        [WebMethod()]
        public void AjouterMetier(string job)
        {
            if (job != "")
            {
                jobs.Add(job);
                Session["jobs"] = jobs;
            }

        }
}
```

I'm beginner in the use of ajax in Asp.net, so i had always the session variables `Session["jobs"]` null and the method **AjouterMetier** was never reached .

- What is the error that I commited?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: if you just type the url `<myserver>/JobsEdition.aspx/AjouterMetier` (where <myserver> is the url to the server your page is on) into your browser's address bar, do you get any ASPX or HTTP error?

Comment: A WebMethod need to be static. public static void AjouterMetier(string job)

Comment: @Samuel when i change it to static ==> i have to change the Jobs list also to static and i got this error `session is unknown type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Webmethod work with a session you need anotate this way [WebMethod(enableSession: true)], Who your Webmethod is static you will need to change List to Static too, To acess a session in in a static method you need to refer a session how HttpContext.Current.Session.

I thik this will solve your problem

Try this

cs

```
static List<string> jobs = new List<string>();
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
public static void AjouterMetier(string job)
{

    if (job != "")
    {
        jobs.Add(job);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["jobs"] = jobs;
    }

}
```

js

```
jQuery('#addjob').click(function () {
            if ($('#metier').val().length > 0) {
                $('.taglist').append('<li style="line-height: 20px"><a href="" style="width:250px" >' + $('#metier').val() + '<span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/AjouterMetier",
                    data: "{'job': '" + $('#metier').val() + "'}",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
                });
            }
            $('#metier').val('');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your adding items to the session:

```
Session["jobs"] = jobs;
```

You might want to initialize the variable by grabbing it from session prior. For instance:

```
public void AjouterMetier(string job)
{
  if (job != "")
  {
    jobs = (List<string>)Session["jobs"] ;
    if( jobs == null )
      jobs = new List<string>();

    jobs.Add(job);
    Session["jobs"] = jobs;
  }
}
```